# Visual Studio Code - how to run `code` command from command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I try to develop an extension which executes this command

```
code $(git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD) -r
```

if the user calls the command `foo`.

This is my **extension.ts**:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('git-open-modified-files.foo', () => {
        // How can I call my `code $(git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD) -r` command here?
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('code $(git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD) -r');    // does not work

    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vscode.commands.executeCommand` is to call a VSC command, you want a shell/terminal command

Use/Try

```javascript
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence', { "text": "code $(git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD) -r\u000D" });
```

Comment: Thank you, it did not worked though, I get `rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: command 'code $(git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD) -r' not found`

Comment: @Black do you have a terminal open. the command given just sends text to the terminal, do you have a git bash shell as terminal

Comment: I had a shell open and VSC has its own shell too.

Comment: the integrated terminal in VSC

Comment: Yes, the integrated terminal. It is open.

Comment: does it work if you type the `code ...` command yourself in the integrated terminal